# Node.js process closing without firing events

Tags: javascript, node.js, process

I'm trying to make a Node.js process run forever in a console window. I have tried using `setInterval(function() {}, 1000)`, and even tried running a HTTP server that did nothing just because I knew HTTP servers are kept running.

Still my program keeps closing without a reason. Also, it does not fire any of the events I know (SIGTERM, SIGINT and exit).

Is there any other way to keep the process running? Or to know what is the reason for it to be closing by itself? It is a bit large for me to post here, but it is basically a bunch of event listeners that are using the mraa library to answer to logic leven changes in GPIO pins.

Comment: Any simple interval timer or open socket or running server will keep node.js from shutting itself down automatically.  You can demonstrate that to yourself with a simple node.js app that is nothing more than `setInterval(function() {console.log("alive")}, 5000)`.  If your app is shutting down even though it has a running interval timer, then you must have some sort of error or other issue that is killing the process.

Comment: @jfriend00 Yes, that's what I thought at first. But my program is closing without displaying any errors, and without firing any of the three events I've listed. I don't know how to find the error that is closing my program.

Comment: Well, we can't likely help when you haven't shared any relevant code.  You can always use the binary search approach where you comment out large blocks of code (except for an interval timer) and see when the problem goes away.  When you comment stuff out, you obviously have to be smart about it not to create new errors.

Comment: @jfriend00 I know it's hard, but I don't know how to share this kind of code. It's based on listening to GPIO pins through the MRAA library. I've never had this kind of problem before, and was wondering if there was another event that nodejs would fire when closing that I was not aware of, or if there was some other way to keep the process running.

Comment: I'd guess that you may have an uncaught exception somewhere.  Simplify the app to almost nothing and then slowly add things back.  You could also use `process.on('exit', fn1).on('SIGINT', fn2).on('SIGTERM', fn3);` set of handlers and see if you learn anything with that.

Comment: when does it close? when you log out or close the terminal?